# I don't have startup disk creator in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I want to make a bootable USB stick on my ubuntu 19.04, the instructions tell me I should have the startup disk creator already installed but I don't. Can I download it from somewhere or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Startup Disk Creator (*usb-creator-gtk*) can be started from the Dash by clicking on the Startup Disk Creator icon or from the terminal with the command `usb-creator-gtk` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, including Ubuntu 19.04.

To verify that Startup Disk Creator is installed run the following command:

```
apt policy usb-creator-gtk
```

Startup Disk Creator can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: I ran the command and got the following:

usb-creator-gtk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.5
  Version table:
     0.3.5 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @AS95, In a standard installation of Ubuntu, you should have the Startup Disk Creator, but it seems to be missing. If you have an internet connection, it should work to install it with the second command line in karel's answer.